# How to extract text from file to file using sed or grep?

Tags: sed, grep, extract

My example string is in txt file /www/meteo/last.txt:

`a:3:{i:0;s:4:"6.13";i:1;s:5:"19.94";i:2;s:5:"22.13";}`

I would like to get line by line 3 numbers from that file to a new file.
(those values is temperature so they are changing in time - every 10 minutes)

New file /www/meteo/new.txt: (line by line)

```
 6.13 
 19.94
 22.13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this awk method

```
awk -F'"' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $2,$4,$6}' last.txt  > new.txt
```

**OutPut:**

```
cat new.txt
6.13
19.94
22.13
```

Comment: I've modified your method. Now it is:

awk -F'"' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $2}' last.txt  > temp1.txt

awk -F'"' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $4}' last.txt  > temp2.txt

awk -F'"' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {print $6}' last.txt  > temp3.txt

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you wanted to use `sed` or `grep`:

`sed -r 's/([^"]*)("[^"]*")([^"]*)/\2\n/g;s/"//g' /www/meteo/last.txt`

`grep -Eo '"[^"]*"' /www/meteo/last.txt | sed 's/"//g'`

If you want a specific value, lets say the second temperature in quotes you can use `sed`: 
`grep -Eo '"[^"]*"' /www/meteo/last.txt | sed -n '2p'`

Comment: Hello, this looks fine to me but I would like to have the output without "..." quota :)

Comment: @Marek I updated the answer to rid the quotes. In general you can take the match and remove the quotes with a simple `sed 's/"//g'`.